# Executing a Cypher query in the Galaxybase studio prompts "Query time exceeded"

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, opencypher

I'm trying to do a cypher query in the graph database Galaxybase, but it prompts "Query time exceed".

```
MATCH (n:`bankid`),(e:`person`)
WHERE n.bankid IN bank_code
AND e.idnumber IN person_code
AND cumulativeinflow > 200000
WITH collect(n.bankid) AS bank_code1,collect(n.bankid) AS bank_code2
MATCH (n:`bankid`),(m:`bankid`),p=(n:`bankid`)-[*0..2]-(m:`bankid`)
WHERE n.bankid IN bank_code1
AND m.bankid IN bank_code2
RETURN p
```

Do the query statements need to be optimized or is there something wrong with the setup of the database management system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database system sets the execution time of the query task, beyond which an error will be reported, and the administrator user can modify the cypher query timeout time in the visualization platform (8888 interface) - system settings - system parameters.